# Orchard CMS - Workflow Send Message to Email List

Tags: orchardcms-1.7

I would like to send an email notification to a distribution list every time I publish a post on my Orchard CMS blog. The list of emails is contained as a list of custom content items that get created as users submit a custom form to subscribe to emails. I know how to use the workflows feature to send an email notification whenever a content item is created to a fixed list of emails, but I would like to be able to send emails to a list derived from an email field value for instances of a custom content item. Is there an existing way to do this in Orchard, or will I have to write a module to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write your own Action and a Token to do that. 
Your Token will be the Distribution List and the Action of Sending of the mail. 
Check orchard.Workflows.Activities, Orchard.Email.Rules (thats the send Email action)